# Parse encoded $_SERVER['request_uri']

Tags: php, url, request

Quick question, `$_SERVER['request_uri']` doesn't contain decoded url but the original one. If I access `http://localhost/asd/%20/` it contains `asd/%20/`. What's the function name to parse it to `asd/ /`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`urldecode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

> Decodes any %## encoding in the given string. Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character.